# Redmine and Subversion

Tags: svn, repository, redmine, webdav

I have problems trying to configure Redmine to use my Subversion repository. I've modified the configuration.yml file so that it calls:

```
scm_subversion_command: svn
```

And also tried to use full path to svn (as suggested by **Andriy Lesyuk**)

```
scm_subversion_command: /usr/bin/svn
```

and I've also enabled 'DAV svn' as shown on this guide here -> http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Repositories_access_control_with_apache_mod_dav_svn_and_mod_perl

This is my dav_svn.conf

```
   # /svn location for users
   PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine
   <Location /svn>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath "/var/svn" 
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
     Satisfy any
     LimitXMLRequestBody 0

     SVNPathAuthz off

     PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
     PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Redmine SVN Repository" 

     #read-only access    
     <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require valid-user
        Allow from redmine.server.ip
        # Allow from another-ip
         Satisfy any
     </Limit>
     # write access
     <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
       Require valid-user
     </LimitExcept>

     ## for mysql
     RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine;host=localhost" 

     RedmineDbUser "redmine" 
     RedmineDbPass "mypassword" 
  </Location>
```

What I get is a circle with a "!" on the settings page, and

> scm command is not available. please check settings on the administration panel

in the project settings->repository page, when I try to add a Subversion repository.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

I'm using Ubuntu Linux as server and when I type

```
svn
```

or

```
svn --version
```

I get the expected output.

I think it might be useful to know also what I've done to install Redmine, so, I followed this guide (installing latest stable 2.3.0 in place of the one written there):
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_212_in_Ubuntu_1210_and_Apache_Passenger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is important to point out the answer of Easly at the end of the comments since this
fixed my problem!

I cited it to push it to top:

Easly:
just to make it clear, i even found where the error was! other then adding the scm_command you need to add the scm_stderr log file, as soon as i've added it, svn started to work on redmine

Answer (score 4):

I tried the things above, but it didn't help.

Additionally, I had to set the ownership of the log file and the write right to the user, who runs Redmine. In my case, that was www-data.

```
# fixed my issue
chown www-data:www-data /var/log/redmine_scm_stderr.log
```

Comment: I guess this answer deserves the tick.